# Invoking dynamic method name (methodname from string)

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, openbd

If I have

```
<cfset methodName = "a">
<cfset object = createObject(...)>
```

How can I call the function named `methodName` from the component `object`. I would expect something along the lines of

```
<cfset object[methodName]()>
```

as would work in JS, but this doesn't seem to work. I know that I could use a `cfinvoke`, however I don't think I need to delve into the reasons why I do not want to use that tag (using it as a temporary fix right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `cfinvoke` as well as `invoke()` in Adobe ColdFusion 10+ for script-based code.

Comment: Sadly `invoke` isn't available in openbd and only work in CF10, going to ask Alan whether it would be a simple addition to get it working openBD, but fair enough.

Comment: I didn't see the openbd tag there. Sorry.

Comment: Could have made it clearer myself, but was sort of hoping there was some universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the unknown/dynamic method to an explicit key in the object and execute it from that key:

```
<cfset methodName = "a">
<cfset object = createObject(...)>
<cfset object.doMethod = object[methodName]>
<cfset object.doMethod()>
```

Still not very elegant, but it avoids `<cfinvoke>` and `evaluate()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's klutzy but, you could always write the line of code to a .cfm file and then cfinclude it.

Answer (score -1):

`cfinvoke` or `evaluate('object.#a#()')` (be sure that you can trust a)

Comment: As I mentioned in all versions of the question I was already aware of `cfinvoke` (bleh) and although `evaluate` is a valid solution I don't think I need to point out why `evaluate` is even worse.